# Fading plots based on a function

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have this plot but it does not do what I want it to do. I have made A MOCK-UP OUTPUT of what I want.

```
 ClearAll[x, xi, σ, n]
 xi = 2; k0 = 5; σ = 2;
 Show[
  Table[
   sol = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == (Sinh[(σ^2) x[t] (t - xi)])/((Cos[2 k0 x[t]]))), x[0] == n}, x[t], {t, 0, 4}];
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], t} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   BaseStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thickness[.001], 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, Medium}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, t}, 
      Directive[
       Opacity[0.02 + (e^(-1/2 (x[t] - xi)^2 σ^2) sqrt (π/
               2) σ (1 + e^(2 x[t] (-xi) σ^2) + 
               2 e^(x[t] (-xi) σ^2) cos (2 k0 x))) /. sol[[1]] //
          First], Blue]]], {n, -3, 3 - 1/4, 1/4}]]
```

This is what it should output with each iteration, the curves are faded based upon the function - such that curves close to the center fade. Notice that the curve holds it opacity all through its progress.

[image]

Comment: Betty,there ar esime syntax errors in your code. For instance `e^` should probably be `E^` (uppercase) or `Exp[...]`. Similarly `sqrt` should be `Sqrt[...]`. Does it get any better if you fix those problems? I also think that your code should probably read `sol = Table[...]`, rather than `Table[sol =...]`.

Comment: Marco not really - the output above is not something that comes from the code I'd written, it what I want to code to produce.

Comment: Did you notice that your `NDSolve` expression does not actually work though? If you try to evaluate it, it returns `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 9.421270636234184`*^-14, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`. Until you solve this issue, you won't be able to obtain a plot no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

```
functions = Table[n x^4 + n/2 x^2 + n/5, {n, -4, 4}];

styled = MapThread[
      Style[#1, Opacity@#2] &,
      {#, Abs@Standardize[#, Mean, 2 StandardDeviation[#]&]& @Range@Length@#}
   ]& @functions;

Plot[
   Evaluate@styled, {x, -0.7, 0.7},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Red]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks right but what if I wanted to use my orginal equation - as I may want to vary it: sol = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == (Sinh[(σ^2) x[t] (t - xi)])/((Cos[2 k0 x[t]]))), x[0] == n}, x[t], {t, 0, 4}]

Comment: thanks for that, but in terms of my function I do not see how it can work, in fact being new to Mathematica it looks like it is only designed for this pattern. Can you please tell me more?

Comment: @Betty Did you notice that your `NDSolve` expression does not actually work though? If you try to evaluate it, it returns `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 9.421270636234184`*^-14, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`. Until you solve this issue, you won't be able to obtain a plot no matter what.